# Windows 10, change size options when connected to External Monitor Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, macbook

I am running Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro, with Boot Camp.  I am running 2 external monitors that run max resolution of 1920 x 1080.  When I am running on the monitors, I need to set the size of all items to Small - 100%.

When I am mobile, I run the MBP at full resolution, but run the size of all items to Larger.

Does anyone know of an automated way that I can get this to switch the scaling level based on if I am connected to external monitor or not? Possibly any applications that will do this.

I have tried Google, and also have searched numerous questions on here, and have not found the answer.

Comment: On what level you want to automate it? Hot plugging/unplugging monitors?!? User login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DPI 1st monitor (200% scale)

[image: Higher DPI on 1st monitor]

For DPI 2nd monitor (100% scale)

[image: Lower DPI monitor]

It is important NOT to use following scaling (it should be set to 100%). By default using MacBook retina driver pack it would be set to 150/200%.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answered the OP's question, but this was very helpful information nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

If defining different users for work with monitors and for mobile is acceptable for you:

- [Since Windows 8.1 you can setup DPI per monitor and this setting is user specific](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#high_dpi_features_in_windows).

If you want to adjust you DPI when you login:

- Unfortunately [Windows don't seems to allow to change DPI programatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you need autostart - in a way you prefer - AutoIt/AutoHotkey script (eventually compiled one) to count/detect your monitors (AutoHotkey -> SysGet -> MonitorCount) and adjust per monitor DPI (not per system DPI - OS restart is required in this case).

If you want kind of hot plug/unplug monitors(?!?):

- You need to extend described above script for monitor count change detection (WM_DISPLAYCHANGE or WM_DEVICECHANGE messages) or check monitor count periodically (GetSystemMetrics -> SM_CMONITORS).